# External static declaration - K&R2

Tags: c, static, language-lawyer, declaration

I'm reading "The C Programming Language," Second Edition, by K&R and on page 83, section 4.6 "Static Variables" K&R state:

> The static declaration, applied to an external variable or function,
>   limits the scope of that object to the rest of the source file being
>   compiled.

**Did K&R actually make a mistake here by giving a wrong semantic for the external static declaration?** Applying static to an external variable or a function does not change the scope. It seems to me that the above sentence states exactly the same as the sentence on page 80, section 4.4 "Scope Rules":

> The scope of an external variable or a function lasts from the point
>   at which it is declared to the end of the file being compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On page 227, K&R describe two kinds of scope: lexical scope and the scope associated with external linkage. Thus, they are using “scope” as a more general term than the current C standard does. Their lexical scope is what the current C standard calls “scope,” and their broader use of scope is what the current C standard calls linkage.